# What is the best way to hide a websites folder/ directory files

Tags: file, directory, document-root

If I would visit my website by "www.mysite.com/img/"

I would see the following:

Parent directory...

folder1

folder2

file1

file2

etc etc..

But what is the **best** way to prevent people from visit my websites folders and file structure?

While still letting pople view eg the images on **the actual website**

I also want to hide eg www.mysite.com/functions/ where I have my php function-files.

Checking on google shows me alot of ways to do this,

**but what is the best and safest way?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your server is Apache you can setup an [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file and build rules to hide/redirect and return a 404 Error page.

If your server is IIS then you can modify the "URL Rewrite" rules in your IIS Manager to return a 404 Error/Forbidden page.

See: [.htaccess tips & tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php)

Answer (score 10):

Create an `index.html` or `index.php` file inside, for example, the `img` folder; so when a visitor attempts to visit `yourwebsite.com/img/` and see the content, `index.html` will be showed instead.

Comment: The problem with this is that the user then knows that that folder exists which doesn't really address the original question.

Comment: Doesn't prevent actually downloading the file