# Hide parent directory /www

Tags: html, web

I am uploading my project containing folders with all the scripts, PHP, CSS etc, and the index.html

Let's say the URL looks like this www.mydomain.com/project/web/index.html

Inside the parent folder "project", all my files are visible and easily accessible to download (which they shouldn't) if they simply enter www.mydomain.com/project/

Question:
Is there any way to HIDE all the parent folders and documents and only make my /index.html accessible?

My server is not an Apache so I can not setup an .htaccess file and build rules to hide/redirect and return a 404 Error page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to hide a websites folder/ directory files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439348/what-is-the-best-way-to-hide-a-websites-folder-directory-files)

Comment: My server is not an Apache so I can not set up an .htaccess file and build rules to hide/redirect and return a 404 Error page.

Comment: What web server *are* you running?

Comment: @Mykita, try to extend your question by providing us more information.

Comment: How do I know what server I am running? I just know that it is not Apache. I am simply hosting my page from a domain provier (https://www.domeneshop.no/)

Comment: At least the domeneshop.no site itself is using apache.

Answer (score 7):

You could set up a `index.html` in your projects folder or any other folder that you don't want them to have access.

Then in those `index.html` pages you can add redirects to push the user to your true homepage. You would place this code in the head of that `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=www.mydomain.com/project/web/">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href = "www.mydomain.com/project/web/"
        </script>
```

I still think the best way is to use a `.htaccess`. But if you have no other choice this will work for folder based access.

This would not prevent people from accessing the file directly such as `www.mydomain.com/project/file.txt`

Comment: What is the role of meta tag here ? how does it work with the url ?

Comment: @bhansa This HTML snippet is really two different redirects. Why two? just to double up. For example the user might block JavaScript, so as a fall back the meta tag will handle the redirection. If you want to know more about that meta tag I would look at this resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me ,didn't know we can use urls in meta.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your server is Apache.

This is from their documentation:

> What is the difference between the old and new webservers?
>   The operating system on all new webservers are running Debian 8 Jessie, up from Debian 7 Wheezy.
>
> Apache is upgraded from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4. If you are running your own .htaccess-file (especially accesscontrol) on your webhotel, this may need to be upgraded. Check Apache-documentation for more information.
>
> We are now using uWSGI to run PHP, instead of suPHP (mod_suphp).

Link to documentation: [FAQ](https://domainname.shop/faq?id=343&section=22)

Link to rewrite_mod for Apache 2.4 [Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try my idea.

1. Create an `index.html` or `index.php` file inside of a folder you dont want the user to access, for example, the `project` folder; so when a user attempts to visit `www.mydomain.com/project` and see the content, the `index.html` will be showed instead. **OR**
2. Create a condition there which `redirect` the user to `index.html` using `php` or `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to tackle this

You can try using a folder structure like Laravel does, setting up a MVC (Model-View-Controller) architecture can restrict to viewing only specific requests.

Following the REST pattern. If someone goes to

```
mydomain.com/project //Returns 404 error
```

The controller for /project must be defined, if it's not defined, it will throw a 404 error

Similarly, if only you define a project view like

```
Route::get('project', 'This is the project page');
```

That's the only way someone can access a /project directory, I would suggest you learn about REST patterns and follow a MVC/MTV responsibility driven design.

Answer (score 0):

Your server appears to be running PHP, at least according to your question. This means that you have most likely done something wrong there. But as Voloshin commented, you need to extend your question. Honestly, scan your PHP to check to see if you have a link that just says "./" instead of "index.html". If you don't have something like that in there, then check all of your `<a href="link" /> link </a>` tags to make sure that you haven't screwed up there. 
All the best with your code!